# mac osx clean command not working under tmux

Tags: macos, tmux

As the title says the error is "terminals database is inaccessible":

```
 » clear                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
terminals database is inaccessible
```

macOS Monterey 12.4

Issue only occurs under tmux + zsh and googling hasn't helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to configure the default terminal to xterm by adding

```
set -g default-terminal xterm-256color
```

to your ~/.tmux.conf

Comment: Thank you Gary! Spent hours and your solution worked!

Comment: This works for me. It was tmux-256color.